# meaning: at three

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What does "at three" mean in the following?

> Lolita, light of my life, fire of my loins. My sin, my soul. Lo-lee-ta: the tip of the tongue taking a trip of three steps down the palate to tap, **at three**, on the teeth. Lo. Lee. Ta.

Does it mean "at step three"? If so, could you offer a similar example of this usage?

Comment: [Here in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22on+my+count+on+three%22) are a couple of written instances of *On my count. **On three*** that definitely match your cited usage (and another one for [***at** three*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ref+start+the+count+at+three%22)). Note that for ascending counts, ***3*** is usually the "trigger" value (as opposed to ***0, zero*** for the more common descending *3, 2, 1, **Go!*** usage). But it's only really 3 in your context because the name ***Lolita*** has 3 syllables.

Answer (score 1):

On the third step.

When you say Lolita you make three consonants, in the first two are "l" and you put your tongue on the roof of the mouth (l is a lateral approxiamant) the third and last consonant is "t", tap your tougue on your teeth (it is a dental plosive)

This is meant to be the ramblings of an obsessed mind. He isn't speaking in complete or well-formed sentences.

We say "at three" or "at/on the count of three" for example when musicians are count in at the start of a song or taking a photograph "At the count of three! One! Two! Three! (click)"

Something similar is said by the Red Queen to Alice in *Through the Looking Glass*, for comic effect, the Queen measures out the ground for her One, Two Three.